# Search on Enterprise keywords or Managed metadata

Tags: sharepoint-online, managed-metadata, office-365, keyword

I'm new to Sharepoint online (Office 365 really), and I'm trying to figure out how to search on Enterprise keywords, on the one hand, and Managed metadata, on the other.

I know I can use a syntax in the search field to search for other metadata values, such as Author:

```
author:"Anders Svensson"
```

Which is documented here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee558911.aspx

But I cannot figure out how to do this for Enterprise keywords (i.e. the general "Tags" that you can set on a document in the "Tags & Notes" dialog).

I tried `keyword:value`but that didn't work. (Obviously the "value" part here used an actual keyword/tag value that I had set on a document)

Also, I wanted to search on a Managed metadata field I created. It's a field called Subject, and it gets it's values from a taxonomy in the Term store.

I tried `subject:value` and `Subject:value`, but neither of them worked.

I cannot find any information on this, no matter how much I Google or search the help...

EDIT:

Please note that I'm trying to do the search in the "Find a file" search field inside the document library.

Also, I'm not sure I understand enterprise keyword functionality as a whole: if I go to the Tags and Notes page (which was there by default) I can click on tags and get documents tagged with it, but if I add a web part with a tag cloud, I get the cloud ok, but clicking on a tag curiously does not show any results...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use only Managed Properties in your search Query.The new column which is you create is actually a crawled property. To include the content and metadata of crawled properties in the search index, you map crawled properties to managed properties.

In case of SharePoint Online, When you create a new site column in a SharePoint list, the search picks up the name of the site column as a new crawled property. SharePoint Online automatically maps the new crawled property to a new auto-generated managed property.So, try searching as `owsSubject:value` or `owssubject:value`

If it don't work, you may need to create Managed Properties , here are the steps : http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/manage-the-search-schema-in-sharepoint-online-HA103628856.aspx#_Toc343168194

Comment: Thanks, but I actually tried all of these options (I found a site while Googling for this), and I tried both exactly as you typed them here, and also with a dash after "ows", and with upper and lowercase on Subject. I also did the manual mapping once, but nothing worked. I only get hits when searching for Subject:value, but that is a free text hit, because it gets everything that has the value text inside the document.

Comment: I had actually tried what you suggested, but I read the link you provided carefully, and tested it again, realizing I hadn't done it correctly the first time. In fact, all I had to do was find the automatically mapped Managed Property created for my Managed Metadata column, and add an alias for it, and then (after waiting for a crawl) it worked! Thanks a lot! I still don't know how to search for simple Enterprise Keywords though, except just using the value, but that returns hits from body text as well. I would have liked to use e.g. "keyword:value"...

Comment: In my case Sharepoint **does not** create crawled properties for new columns.

Answer (score 2):

By Now, you can simply query for enterprise Keywords using:

```
tags:Keyword
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/116984)

Comment: Does not work for me. Do I need to manually update some indexes or wait some days, until a new enterprise keyword can be found?

Answer (score 1):

You said you are entering the keywords like this: [I would have liked to use e.g. "keyword:value"...] 
You are supposed to enter them like this[e.g. "keywords:value"...] }. You are missing the "S" on keywords. Good luck!

Comment: Ha...that missing "s" solved the problem for me too, thanks ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same requirement and was able to search for the enterprise keywords values using using owstaxIdTaxKeyword:value.