# Search for Metadatacolumn doesnt return a result eg. "Customer:Bob". Full-text search works

Tags: search, search-results

I want to allow our users to search for metadata using keywords. For example "Name:Document1". This works for the standard columns but not for custom ones.
What I mean is, "Name:Document1" works but "Customer:Bob" doesnt work.

Searching in google the whole day still doesnt give me an answer. 
I saw this post: [Search on Enterprise keywords or Managed metadata](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/61509/search-on-enterprise-keywords-or-managed-metadata) which is almost the same as I want to do.
The answer states that I should set up managed properties. I did this but it still doesnt work.

If I search for Bob without specifying the column it returns the right file. But it will also return all files that have "Bob" in any column. And I dont want this to happen.

```
Propertyname: CustomerOWSTEXT
Alias: Customer
Crawled Properties: 

ows_q_TEXT_Customer
ows_Customer
```

I didnt need to create this property because it was already there. Therefore the Name. I read that ows_Customer should be the right one to chose but ows_q_TEXT_Customer is also there and I dont know where it came from.

The metadatacolumn are not managed metadata.

I've already reset the whole searchindex but it still doenst give me any results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track, make sure you do a full crawl to populate the index with the managed properties. You need to do this anytime you make changes to the managed properties, adding crawl properties or adding new managed properties.

The items starting ows_ are crawled properties and you can map multiple crawled properties to a managed property. These are automagically created by the search process as columns in lists, libraries etc are crawled.

You will need to query using the name of the managed property so CustomerOWSText:Bob.

Of course this isn't a great user experience so I would suggest you setup a custom search result page And custom result type.
This can be setup to prepends the CustomerOWSText: to the query.

A guide can be found here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2012/10/09/build-a-specialized-search-experience-in-minutes-with-sharepoint-2013.aspx
 for setting up a PDF search result type.
You should be able to setup the query with value CustomerOWSText:{searchterms} instead.

Comment: Thanks. Using CustomerOWSText:Bob actually works.
I might need to search multiple columns at the same time. So I cant use a custom search result. 
I renamed the CustomerOWSText to Customer. But I still dont get results for Customer. Bob. But i still get results for CustomerOWSText:Bob.
Do I have to do additional things besides renaming it?

Comment: Not tried renaming a auto created managed property not sure if that will work. At leastdo a full crawl after the change. You can cover multiple columns by using the OR query keyword CustomerOWSText:Bob OR AnotherColumnOWSText:Bob

Comment: To clarify, all columns are not automatically converted to Managed Properties, only site columns are converted. Regular list columns are converted to crawled properties but not managed properties. Also, automatic managed properties are always TEXT.

Answer (score 0):

You managed property needs to be Queryable and Retreivable.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219669.aspx#MP_Overview